# Continuously scrolling caroufredsel ticker with variable width items

Tags: caroufredsel

I would like to create a continuously scrolling ticker which has got variable width items in it.  This is going to be used for a news ticker where the news items are aligned one after each other depending on their width according to the news title length.  I would need them to continuously scroll towards the left in a continuous manner in an equal, linear easing manner.

Is this possible through caroufredsel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set duration to .1

```
$("#foo").carouFredSel({ 
    scroll: { 
        duration: 0.1 
    } 
});
```

Source:
http://support.dev7studios.com/discussions/caroufredsel/UC-951092

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this demo:

http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/23/

Comment: Thanks for this @Snow, something like what I needed as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this example
http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/continuously-scrolling.php
I think you just need to add - items: {width: "variable"} - and will work

Comment: I went already on such link but it didn't work.  Do you have any working online examples with variable width items continuous scrolling?  Scroller works for variable widths non continuous scrollers but not for continuous scrollers :/

Comment: try with this
'code'
$("#foo").carouFredSel({
 width: "variable",
 items: {
  width: "variable"
 }
 auto : {
  items    : 5,
  duration  : 7500,
  easing   : "linear",
  timeoutDuration : 0,
  pauseOnHover : "immediate"
 }
});
'code'